# context free grammar that generates binary all numbers divisible by 3

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I'm struggling with the grammar that generates all binary numbers divisible by 3
I know that for a binary number to be divisible by 3 the sum of 1s in even bits mines the sum of 1s in odd bits must be divisible by 3.
After some googling, I found that you can do the dfa of it then convert it to cfg and you can get:
\begin{align*}
S &\to 0S \mid 1A \mid \epsilon \\
A &\to 0B \mid 1S  \\
B &\to 1B \mid 0A 
\end{align*}

I am surprised that this homework takes place before the lectures for finite automata, So, I have no idea how to get this grammar, may anyone explain.

UPDATE:

Thanks to Brain, motivated by his idea I've come to the following grammar which basically almost the same to the one I posted above:
The Idea is if a binary number concatenated by a 0 to the right the result is the number multiplied by 2 if it concatenated by 1 the result is the number multiplied by 2 plus 1
Eg:
$$
W = 10 = (2)_{10}, \text{ then }  W0 = 100 =  (4)_{10} \\
W = 10 = (2)_{10}, \text{ then }  W1 = 101 =  (5)_{10}
$$
by this logic we can denote the following states:
$$
S: \text{ binary numbers divisible by 3 with rest 0 } \\
A: \text{ binary numbers divisible by 3 with rest 1 } \\
B: \text{ binary numbers divisible by 3 with rest 2}
$$
therefore:

$
S:  W = 3k, \text{ } W0 = 3k\text{(Go to S)},\text{ } W1 = 3k + 1\text{(Go to A)} \\
A:  W = 3k + 1,\text{ } W0 = 3k + 2\text{(Go to B)},\text{ } W1 = 3k \text{(Go to S)} \\
B:  W = 3k + 2,\text{ } W0 = 3k + 1\text{(Go to A)},\text{ } W1 = 3k + 2 \text{(Go to B)} \\ 
$
Hence, the following grammar:
\begin{align*}
S &\to S0 \mid A1 \mid \epsilon \\
A &\to B0 \mid S1  \\
B &\to A0 \mid B1 
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you missing the production rule for $B$?

Comment: @JohnDouma sorry a typo, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to approach the problem of designing such a grammar without reference to automata. Imagine building the number from right to left, one bit at a time. At each stage we are about to write a bit in an even position or an odd position, and $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}$ is congruent to $0,1$, or $2$ modulo $3$, where $s_{\text{even}}$ is the number of $1$ bits in even positions so far, and $s_{\text{odd}}$ is the number of $1$ bits in odd positions so far. (I am numbering the positions from the right.) Thus, at each stage of generating a bit string we are in one of $2\cdot 3=6$ possible states, and I’ll assign a nonterminal to each of them as follows:

- $S$: odd position, $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv0\pmod3$
- $A$: even position, $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv0\pmod3$
- $B$: odd position, $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv1\pmod3$
- $C$: even position, $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv1\pmod3$
- $D$: odd position, $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv2\pmod3$
- $E$: even position, $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv2\pmod3$

Now it’s quite easy to come up with the needed productions. At the beginning we’re in state $S$, about to write a bit in an odd position when $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv0\pmod3$. If we write a $0$, $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}$ doesn’t change, but we’ll be writing a the next bit in an even position, so we want to be in state $A$; this means that there should be a transition $S\to A0$. If instead we write a $1$, $s_{\text{odd}}$ increases by $1$, so that we now have $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv2\pmod3$, and we’ll be writing the next bit in an even position, so we want to be in state $E$; thus, there should be a transition $S\to E1$. Finally, because at the moment $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text{odd}}\equiv0\pmod3$, we do currently have a multiple of $3$, so we want to be able to stop here; we arrange that by having a transition $S\to\epsilon$.

If we carry out the same kind of analysis for each of the other five nonterminals, we get the following productions:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to A0\mid E1\mid\epsilon\\
&A\to S0\mid D1\mid\epsilon\\
&B\to C0\mid A1\\
&C\to B0\mid S1\\
&D\to E0\mid C1\\
&E\to D0\mid B1
\end{align*}$$

These do allow the empty word to be generated (via $S\Rightarrow\epsilon$); if this is not wanted, it can be eliminated by adding a nonterminal $X$ with productions $X\to A0\mid E1\mid\epsilon$, eliminating the production $S\to\epsilon$, and replacing the productions $A\to S0$ and $C\to S1$ by $A\to X0$ and $C\to X1$, respectively.

Clearly the resulting grammar is not has more nonterminals and more productions that are actually necessary, but I think that its construction and operation are relatively straightforward.

Comment: Thank you Brain for the answer, very helpful. One question may sound trivial but why when we have a binary number 0 modulo 3 concatenated with a 1 gives a binary number modulo 2 (S-->A1) for example and same for the others, is there a rule behind that, I know when adding a 0 to the right we multiply by 2 when adding a 1 we multiply by 2 and add 1, but it seem a bit ..., can elaborate it please?

Comment: @ahmedben: You’re welcome. It’s not the number itself that I’m looking at modulo $3$: it’s the number of $1$ bits in even positions minus the number in odd positions. If that difference is congruent to $0$ modulo $3$, and I write a $1$ in an odd position, I’ve increased $s_{\text{odd}}$ by $1$, so $s_{\text{even}}-s_{\text_{odd}}$ is decreased by $1$. Thus, it is now congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$, which means that it’s congruent to $2$ modulo $3$. All of the other changes can be checked by the same sort of calculation.

Comment: @brian-m-scott: Alright, now I understand the idea, btw I've posted an update can you check it out?

Comment: @ahmedben: I will take a look, but it will have to wait till tomorrow.

Comment: @brian-m-scott: Yes sure, and I really appreciate the help thanks again.

Comment: @ahmedben: Looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Number the bits from left to right, starting with $1$.  We imagine adding bits to the front of the string as they are read.  $S$ is the state where the sum of the odd-numbered bits equals the sum of the even-numbered bits, modulo $3$.  If we read a  $0$ this doesn't change, so we're still in state $S$.  If we read a $1$, the odd-numbered bit are $1$ more than the even-numbered bits, again modulo $3$.  Can you figure it out from here?  What is state B?  Notice that when we read a new bit, the old odd-numbered bits become even-numbered, and vice-versa.

BTW, this grammar allows the empty string as a binary number.  We can avoid this by using $S$ only as the initial state, and making another state, say $C$ to represent equality.